# PHP DOTNET works on localhost but not on GoDaddy Shared Linux Hosting

Tags: c#, php, linux

I am using *PHP DOTNET* class in my PHP code. I have registered the dll file in the GAC and the entire code works perfectly on localhost. But when uploaded to my Godaddy Linux Shared hosting, it doesn't work and gives a HTTP error 500.

On checking the error_log file I saw **PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'COM' not found** which (I think after some research) means that the COM_DOTNET class in not enabled in PHP.

I am using PHP version 7.1 on my Linux hosting.

### Things I have tried

I have already tried to enable the COM_DOTNET extension from php.ini file.
I have also tried contacting Godaddy support but they can't seem to figure out what extension I am talking about and keep telling me that you can't run .net files on linux.

I have checked my phpinfo() as well can't seem to find the COM Class.

Another thing that I tried is going to CPanel Dashboard and tried to enable it through the list of PHP Extensions listed there. But can't seem to find it there as well.

After all this now I am thinking,  can I use the DOTNET class on a Linux Hosting at all? 
Or can it be only used on a windows hosting?

Does anyone know anything about this? Please help

Comment: COM is only on Windows. You can’t use it on Linux

Comment: Okay got it. So do you suggest getting a windows hosting for the same?

Comment: @akshaydoshi Yes, you need to purchase windows hosting, you can check asphostportal.com. It is good choice for windows hosting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. What I ended up doing is I got a windows VPS and used it. Shared hosting doesn't work in this case.